# Drupal 7 contexual filter display block based on node reference

Tags: views, entities

I have been going around in circles with this for a few hours now... Time to ask for help!!

I have two Content Types:

1: Book

2: Reader

The `Book` Content Type has a `node reference` field which is a select list of readers create with the `Reader` Content Type.

This is all set up and working fine.

Now the issue with my views:

I have a view with is a block containing the `Reader` fields. What I want to do is have it when the `Book` node is loaded my block shows underneath with the referenced `reader` details. Also if no reader is referenced then no block shows up.

I have spent some time in `Relationship` and `Contextual Filters` but can't get it to work.

The book URL is formatted like this:

books/[book-title]

I tired using 'raw value from url' in `Contextual Filters` as setting it to the 2nd argument but that didn't work either.

If anyone can help me out here I would be very much appreciative.

Thanks
C

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250743/drupal-7-contexual-filter-display-block-based-on-node-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to 'Provide default value' and set to 'PHP Code'. Then use the following to return a specific portion of the URL. The url argument starts from 0 ($theurl[0]).

```
$theurl = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET["q"]);
$theurl = explode("/", $theurl);
return $theurl[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a simple content view of readers add fields and add a contextual filter of field_book or whatever is the name of reference field and choose option "When the filter value is NOT in the URL" -> "Provide default value" -> "Content ID from URL" and save.

Answer (score 0):

Views blocks will not look at path, you need a module like below to pass argument to views block:

```
function mymodule_block_view($delta){
    $block = array();

    $book_id = arg(1);
    //check $book_id is really a book id
    $nodes = views_get_view_result('xxxx', 'yyyy', $book_id);
    if (count($nodes)):
        $block['subject'] = t('Readers');
        $block['content'] = views_embed_view('xxxx', 'yyyy', $book_id),
    endif;

    return $block; //return empty $block will hide entire block
}
```